# How to call Java Bean from Spring DAO with JDBC

Tags: java, spring, teradata, dao

I have created the following Java Bean using the wizard inside of Eclipse. I have a simple parameterized SQL statement in this and I want to know how I can actually call it / execute it.

I am 100% new to Java/Spring so sorry if this is obvious or if my question does not make sense.

The end goal here is that we can use JDBC to connect to Teradata to submit SQL queries and return them to a Spring DAO.

The wizard generated the following two .java files:

GeedID.java

```java
package test.repoo;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * This class is a Java Bean that executes and return results 
 * for the SQL Statement:
 *
 * select * from databasename.tablename where X_id = ?
 *
 */
public class GedID {

    private DataSource dataSource = null;
    private Integer id = null;
    private ArrayList<GedIDDomainObj1> gedIDDomainObj1List = new ArrayList<GedIDDomainObj1>();

    /**
     * Returns Data source for a connection to execute the SQL statement 
     *
     * @return dataSource 
     */
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return this.dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Sets Data source for a connection to execute the SQL statement 
     *
     * @param dataSource 
     */
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Get Parameter for SQL statement
     *
     * @return id 
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * Set Parameter for the SQL statement
     *
     * @param id 
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
         * Get the next result set
         * 
         * @param cStmt - CallableStatement
         * @return ResultSet
         * @throws SQLException
         */

    private ResultSet getNextResultSet(CallableStatement cStmt) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        while (cStmt.getMoreResults() || cStmt.getUpdateCount() != -1) {
            rs = cStmt.getResultSet();
            if (rs != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return rs;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array of generated classes for result set of a SQL statement
     *
     * @return GedIDDomainObj1[] 
     */
    public GedIDDomainObj1[] getGedIDDomainObj1List() {
        GedIDDomainObj1[] returnList = new GedIDDomainObj1[this.gedIDDomainObj1List.size()];
        return this.gedIDDomainObj1List.toArray(returnList);
    }

    /**
     * Get SQL Query
       *
     * @return Query String
     */
    public String getQueryStatement() {
        return "select * from databasename.tablename where X_id = ?";

    }

    /**
     *  This method executes the SQL statement   
     *
     *  @throws SQLException - error executing SQL statement
     */
    public void execute() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        try {
            execute(con);
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get CallableStatement to Execute SQL statement
       *
     * @param con - JDBC connection to database
     * 
       * @throws SQLException - error creating CallableStatement
     */
    private CallableStatement getCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement cStmt = con.prepareCall(getQueryStatement());
        return cStmt;
    }

    /**
     *  This method executes the SQL statement 
     *  
     *  @param con - JDBC connection to a database
     * 
     *  @throws SQLException - error executing SQL statement
     */
    private void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {

        CallableStatement cStmt = getCallableStatement(con);
        try {
            execute(cStmt);
        } finally {
            cStmt.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     *  This method executes a SQL Statement
     *  
     *  @param cStmt- JDBC CallableStatement
     *
     *  @throws SQLException - error executing SQL statement
     */
    private void execute(CallableStatement cStmt) throws SQLException {
        cStmt.setInt(1, id);
        boolean hasResultSets = cStmt.execute();
        if (hasResultSets || (cStmt.getUpdateCount() != -1)) {
            ResultSet rs = cStmt.getResultSet();
            if (rs == null) {
                rs = getNextResultSet(cStmt);
            }
            gedIDDomainObj1List.clear();
            while (rs.next()) {
                GedIDDomainObj1 gedIDDomainObj1 = new GedIDDomainObj1();
                gedIDDomainObj1.setX_Id(rs.getInt(1));
                gedIDDomainObj1.setX_Name(rs.getString(2));
                gedIDDomainObj1.setX_Group_Name(rs.getString(3));
                gedIDDomainObj1List.add(gedIDDomainObj1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

GedIDDomainObj1.java

```java
package test.repoo;

import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.String;

/**
 * This is the helper class which is the result set row of the 
 * following SQL statement: 
 *
 * select * from databasename.tablename where X_id = ?
 *
 * From the class  GedID
 */
public class GedIDDomainObj1 {

    private Integer X_Id = null;
    private String X_Name = null;
    private String X_Group_Name = null;

    /**
     * Sets data item from a result set of a SQL statement
     *
     * @param X_Id 
     */
    public void setX_Id(Integer X_Id) {
        this.X_Id = X_Id;
    }

    /**
     * Returns data item from a result set of a SQL statement
     *
     * @return Integer 
     */
    public Integer getX_Id() {
        return this.X_Id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets data item from a result set of a SQL statement
     *
     * @param X_Name 
     */
    public void setX_Name(String X_Name) {
        this.X_Name = X_Name;
    }

    /**
     * Returns data item from a result set of a SQL statement
     *
     * @return String 
     */
    public String getX_Name() {
        return this.X_Name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets data item from a result set of a SQL statement
     *
     * @param X_Group_Name 
     */
    public void setX_Group_Name(String X_Group_Name) {
        this.X_Group_Name = X_Group_Name;
    }

    /**
     * Returns data item from a result set of a SQL statement
     *
     * @return String 
     */
    public String getX_Group_Name() {
        return this.X_Group_Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Spring provides a template class called JdbcTemplate that makes it easy to work with SQL relational databases and JDBC" [spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/)